# 2022 Gr11 Fermat math contest question #20

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math, fractions

**Question:** A sequence of numbers $t_1, t_2, t_3$,... has its terms defined by $t_n = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}$ for every integer $n \geq 1.$ For example, $t_4 = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{6}$. What is the largest positive integer k for which the sum of the first k terms (that is, $t_1 + t_2 +\cdots+t_{k-1} + t_k$) is less than 1.499?

**Correct answer:** 1998

**My solution:** First, to find the sum of all numbers from $t_1$ to $t_k$, I wrote the equation $\frac{(\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+2}) * k}{2}$, note: I got $\frac{2}{3}$ from $\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{1+2}$. Next, I just substituted the 5 options this question gave me into my equation (this is a multiple choice question), but I got around $666$ when I substituted the different options which is no where near $1.499$. This means the problem is somewhere in my equation for the sum of all numbers from $t_1$ to $t_k$, but I do not know where I went wrong in my equation, or even if it was the right first step to solving this question.

Comment: Please format your question with MathJax.  We can read the subscripts much better, seeing $t_{k-1}$ instead of tk-1.  Your definition of tn=1/n-1/n+2 leads to tn=2.  I suspect you mean $t_n=1/n-1/(n+2)$  Then you are confusing the number of terms, which you have as $666$ with the desired sum of $1.499$.

Comment: Okay, I do not know how to do that but I'll figure it out

Comment: See the FAQ for a link

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it. But what do you mean I am confusing the terms? The sum I got for substituting the different options was around 666, then I said it is no where near 1.499, which as stated in the question, the sum should be less than 1.499. It seems clear to me.

Comment: Your equation looks like the one for the sum of an arithmetic series. This series is not arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Given, $$t_n=\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+2}$$ we get $$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k t_n=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac1n-\frac{1}{n+2}$$$$= \sum_{n=1}^k\frac1n-\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n+2}$$
Reindexing the second sum and replacing $n+2=i$, we get $$S_k=  \sum_{n=1}^k\frac1n- \sum_{i=3}^{k+2}\frac1k$$$$=1+\frac12-\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}=\frac{k(3k+5)}{2(k+1)(k+2)}$$ Now, given that $S_k<1.499$ we infer that $$1.5-\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}<1.499$$ or that $$\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}>0.001$$

---

To better visualise the reindexing, we can write $$S_k=\left(\color{red}{1+\frac12}+ \frac13+ …+ \frac{1}{k}\right)-\left(\frac13+ \frac14+…+ \frac{1}{k}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}}\right)$$ where the $\displaystyle  \frac13+ …+ \frac{1}{k}$ gets cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

$S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k t_n = \sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2} = A_k - B_k< 1.499$. Now, since $B_k = A_{k+2} - \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}$,
$$
S_k = A_k - A_{k+2} + \frac{3}{2} = -\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2} + 1.5 < 1.499.
$$
This gives
$\frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+2} > 1.5 - 1.499 = 0.001 = \frac{1}{2000} + \frac{1}{2000}$.

Therefore $k+2$ can not exceed 2000 so $k = 1998$.